# Where can I read detailed sequence of events in court cases?

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, civil-procedure

I am a graduate student but not a lawyer, so I have access to databases that might be needed for this through the university library website.

I am looking for fun reading, mostly. I was once told that medievalists could get a good grasp of daily life in medieval ages by reading court cases and legal documents, which got me thinking that perhaps I could get my hands on contemporary legal cases which detail the sequence of events that eventually ended up in court. That would be delightful to read for fun, I think.

I did some searching but found nothing like this or could not find my way around the websites I found (I found BAILII, but I am not in the UK, so I am not partial towards UK law).

I am mostly interested in tort law and criminal law.

I would be very grateful if you could oblige me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better asked on https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch how could a question about researching court decisions possibly be better suited to [Academia.SE] than to [Law.SE]?

Answer (score 2):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

German courts have to give the *Urteilsbegründung*, the explanation or justification of their decision. This is first given verbally, during the sentencing, and then in longer written form a few weeks or months later. The *Urteilsbegründung* explains what the court believes did happen, according to which evidence, where they did disregard testimony as not credible or relevant, and how that translates into legal categories.

You can find many of them [online](https://openjur.de/u/59855.html), but of course only in German. At times the [names](http://juris.bundesgerichtshof.de/cgi-bin/rechtsprechung/document.py?Gericht=bgh&Art=en&nr=131541&pos=0&anz=1) are partially redacted even if they are widely known in public, this practice is supposed to assist with the future rehabilitation of the inmates.